# Javascript syntax semicolon

Tags: javascript, if-statement, eval

I have this JavaScript code which I want to know what exactly is happening with the semicolon after the `{`.

```
if(buttonid=='save') {

    if (eval(formSaveCallback)) {;  //what is the use of this semicolon

        //Some code

    }

}
```

Comment: semicolon has nothing to do with the eval

Comment: Thanx. but do you have any idea what is the use of this semicolon?

Comment: The semicolon there is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the use of `;` in each and every line of code? The answer is the same for this too.

Comment: so you mean this is indicating the end of the statement. Is it?

Comment: Yupp an empty line (statement)